# Cannot Get PHP Code Snippet to Run in Woocommerce Template File

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

Ok so I'm using Woocommerce Point of Sale and Woocommerce Order Barcodes.

Woocommerce Order Barcodes provides a php code snippet (See Below) that is supposed to allow me to add an orders barcode into anyfile I choose, just by getting **$order_id** filled with the correct order id.

```
echo WC_Order_Barcodes()->display_barcode($order_id);
```

So I want to insert this php code snippet in my Woocommerce POS Printable Receipt Template File (See File Code Below, unsure if I can provide the whole file due to it being licensed.). The problem I'm having is getting the json data stored to get it to play nicely inside of `<?php ?>`. To successfully call the order id I have to use **{{id}}**. Trying to add this code to my PHP code Snippet breaks the entire POS. Trying to call the ID using numerous text book php methods either does nothing or breaks the POS. I have tried contacting the company but yet to receive a response except an automated one saying they are focusing on developing and it will be a while before I get a response.

```
<table class="order-info">
  <tr>
    <th><?php /* translators: woocommerce */ _e( 'Order Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td>{{order_number}} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><?php _e( 'Order Date', 'woocommerce-pos' ); ?></th>
    <td>{{formatDate completed_at format="MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{#if cashier}}
  <tr>
    <th><?php _e( 'Cashier', 'woocommerce-pos' ); ?></th>
    <td>{{cashier.first_name}} {{cashier.last_name}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/if}}
  <tr>
    <th><?php _e( 'Payment Method', 'woocommerce-pos' ); ?></th>
    <td>{{payment_details.method_title}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{#if billing_address.email}}
  <tr>
    <th><?php /* translators: woocommerce */ _e( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td>{{billing_address.email}}</td>
  </tr>
```

I have also tried using the ID to call the barcode image directly in `<IMG src="">` and as shown below in an iframe, but the `{{id}}` doesn't play nicely inside the parentheses

```
<iframe src="https://www.my_URL.com/?wc_barcode={{id}}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone wondering what the problem was. For some reason the handlebarsjs doesn't notice it's variable calls when inside double quotes"" To get it to work I had to put the iframe src in single quotes like below:

```
<iframe src='https://www.my_URL.com/?wc_barcode={{id}}'></iframe>
```

I was not able to get the handlebarsjs variables inside of the php tags. But I did not try to hard after getting the iframe way to work.